# How do I access item key names in a dictionary and then find the value? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm making a programming language and I'm having trouble with variables. I've made the script add a value and key to a dictionary when it detects the int keyword like this:

```
int var_name=5
```

but I'm having trouble with accessing that dictionary. I want it to access that variable in say a print so you can do

```
int a=5
print a
```

and it'll output 5. So it'll search among the keys and if the string value in the print is in there it'll return the value. Would I do a conditional using the in keyword? Should I use a loop, and if so how would I do it? Should I use a function?

This is the code for the dictionary

```
class my_dictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self = dict()

    def add(self, key, value):
        self[key] = value
dict_obj = my_dictionary

dict_obj.add("b", 5)
print(dict_obj)
```

It's much longer than that, I didn't want to crowd the page.

Comment: What's the point of `my_dictionary` wrapping `dict`? Just use a dict directly. If you want to "search among the keys and if the string value in the print is in there it'll return the value", use `dict_obj["a"]` or `dict_obj[some_var]` (but please come up with a better variable name for the dict!). If the value might be missing use `dict.get("a", "default value of some kind")` Also, `dict_obj = my_dictionary` doesn't invoke the initializer--you probably meant `my_dictionary()`.

Comment: You're making _a programming language_, yet you don't know how to retrieve a value from a Python dictionary? [Please read the docs on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

Comment: I watched a talk recently that said if you have a class with 2 methods and one method is init you should just have a function. Especially when you are using a built-in.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to add a new key:value pair to a dict and then print a specific key? `d = dict(); d["b"] = 5; print(d["b"])`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Could you do that as a response instead of comment so I can verify it as the answer? ggorlen?

Comment: Also ForceBru I've never been good with dictionaries and I havn't used them much until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get` method on a dict.

Example:

```
a = dict()
a["b"] = 5
a.get("b") # returns 5
a.get("c", None) # returns None
```

The second parameter for the `get` method is the default value to be returned if a key is not found in a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have a get method. You can add an optional second parameter to define a default fallback:
    print(dict_obj.get(key))